# Wordpress custom taxonomy

Tags: php, categories, custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm using a custom taxonomy called 'product_cat' and post type called 'product', I'm trying to display all parent terms, child terms and grandchild terms within the taxonomy.

So I get a list like this, But I only want the grandchild terms to be displayed if I'm on the child page.

```
Courses (parent)
- Industry (child)
-- Industry One (grandchild)
-- Industry Two (grandchild)
-- Industry Three( grandchild)
- Trade (child)
-- Trade One (grandchild)
-- Trade Two (grandchild)
-- Trade Three (grandchild)

Essential Packages (parent)
- Construction (child)
-- Construction One (grandchild)
-- Construction Two (grandchild)
-- Construction Three (grandchild)
```

I'm currently using this snippet to try and help me but its not working the way I'm wanting it to.

```
<?php
    $taxonomyName = "product_cat";   
    $parent_terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('include' =>'67', 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));   
    echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($parent_terms as $pterm) {
            echo '<li>';
                echo '<a href="#">'.$pterm->name.'</a>'; // Child 
                $terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array( 'child_of' =>'67', 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));
                echo '<ul class="children">';
                    foreach ($terms as $term) {
                        echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">'.$term->name.'<span class="count">'.$term->count.'</span></a></li>';  // GrandChild
                    }
                echo '</ul>'; 
            echo '</li>'; 
        }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

If anyone could help me out and point me into the right direction I'd really appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1):

[get_terms();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) accept **include** as an array, you are trying with a string term id instead of array, try this

```
$parent_terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('include' => array('67'), 'orderby' => 'slug', 'hide_empty' => false));
```